# Question about definition of a regular point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It says on Wikipedia: A general algebraic variety V being defined as the common zeros of several polynomials, the condition on a point P of V to be singular point is that the Jacobian matrix of the first order partial derivatives of the polynomials has a rank at P that is lower than the rank at other points of the variety.

I am a bit confused with "the rank of the Jacobian matrix at $p$ being lower than other points"... It is not clear to me what they mean by other points (like any other point?) and I find this confusing. I was wondering if someone could clarify what is meant here. Thank you!

Comment: That is not well expressed. The set of regular points is dense in the variety. What the quote basically means is that if you look at the rank of the Jacobian at the rank at P and the rank at a general point (which will be regular), the former will be lower.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Do you happen to know how the regular point is actually defined? I am still a little confused about it...

Comment: [these notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf) are a quite elementary introduction. You might want to take a look at chapter 4.4. Proposition 4.4.8 is the statement you are looking for.